# MySQL GROUP BY functional dependence in subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query to find duplicate rows in a table of people (including each duplicate):

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE CONCAT(firstName,lastName) IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(firstName,lastName) AS name
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY CONCAT(firstName,lastName)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

When running this in MySQL 8.0.19 with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled, it fails with the following error:

> Query 1 ERROR: Expression #1 of HAVING clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Person.firstName' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I can't figure out how to fix this. I tried changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(CONCAT(firstName,lastName))` but that didn't help.

What's odd is that a) it runs fine in MariaDB 10.2, with or without ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, and b) running the subquery by itself causes no issue.

What am I doing wrong? It almost seems like a bug in MySQL.

[edit]: I certainly appreciate alternative solutions to my query, however I'm really interested in an answer as to why my error is occurring.

Comment: Does `firstName='Song', lastName='Ji Yang'` and `firstName='Song Ji', lastName='Yang'` records must be detected as a duplicated ones?

Comment: @Akina, yes those two records should be detected as duplicates.

Comment: If so pay attention that you MUST add a delimiter during concatenation! Because direct concatenation will give two different values, `'SongJi Yang'` and `'Song JiYang'` respectively. And you MUST normalize the delimiters in values - imagine that there are 2 or 3 space chars between words in the values...

Comment: @Akina, understood, this is taken care of in my actual query.

Answer (score 1):

try like below it will do the same that you tried

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE (firstName,lastName) IN (
    SELECT firstName,lastName
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY firstName,lastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not merge fields:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE (firstName,lastName) IN (
    SELECT firstName,lastName AS name
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY firstName,lastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Or use ANY_VALUE() function:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE CONCAT(firstName,lastName) IN (
    SELECT ANY_VALUE(CONCAT(firstName,lastName)) AS name
    FROM Person
    GROUP BY CONCAT(firstName,lastName)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Please avoid starting long discussions under other people's answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the ANY_VALUE method does indeed work for me! But do you have any ideas as to what is actually causing my error?

Comment: @Gannet This is MySQL issue - it does not detect that expressions used in GROUP BY and in output are the same even literally. Even when using output field name in GROUP BY: `SELECT CONCAT(firstName,lastName) AS name FROM Person GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` causes the same error.

Comment: So you think this is just a limitation of MySQL and ANY_VALUE would be the "correct" way to resolve it? Or is it a bug that I should report?

Comment: @Gannet `ANY_VALUE()` is a function whose purpose is to eliminate the problems of multi-meaning of non-grouped fields in a group. *Or is it a bug* I doubt. It is SQL mode-dependent, which is described in User Manual. So it is a feature.

Comment: Yes, but there are no non-grouped fields here! As you said above, it is not correctly detecting the obvious functional dependency, meaning the error is logically incorrect and it is an issue with MySQL. So either a) the issue is a known limitation that MySQL can't easily fix and I should use ANY_VALUE() as a workaround, or b) the issue a bug that I should report. I guess I should just get in touch with MySQL to find out :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write your query with exists logic:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM Person p1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person p2
              WHERE p2.firstName = p1.firstName AND
                    p2.lastName = p1.lastName AND
                    p2.id <> p1.id);
```

This effectively says to select every person for whom we can find another, different, person (going by the primary key `id` column, or whatever the PK might be), with same first and last name.

The following index may speed up the above query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Person (lastName, firstName);
```

This should allow the exists lookup to evaluate quickly.  Note that on InnoDB, MySQL should automatically cover `id` by adding it to the end of the above two-column index.

Regarding your error, I can't help but wonder if perhaps the problem is that you did not use proper aliases in the subquery, leading MySQL to think that you are referring to the columns in the outer query.  Try this version:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM Person p1
WHERE CONCAT(firstName, lastName) IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(p2.firstName, p2.lastName)
    FROM Person p2
    GROUP BY CONCAT(p2.firstName, p2.lastName)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Comment: query 1 - where you have taken from that some `id` exists? query 2 - will not help.

Comment: @Akina If no primary key exist, then the OP should first fix that.  In general _every_ table should have a primary key.

Comment: Why are you starting a lengthy discussion under my answer, when my suggestion to use `EXISTS` is most likely the most efficient method to solve the OP's question?

Comment: I'm not arguing that WHERE EXISTS is more effective then WHERE IN - I'm just saying that it may not be applicable in this particular case.

Comment: I don't know why but your 'exists' suggestion takes a CRAZY long time (45s) to execute with my dataset of ~12k rows. Thanks for your suggestion regarding the error, however adding the alias did not resolve it.

Comment: @Gannet Maybe you simply have no proper index for this query, and fullscan is used...

Comment: @Gannet Check my updated answer for an index option which should improve performance.

Comment: @Tim, sorry forgot to mention I changed it to do CONCAT. Your answer is great when comparing the names as-is.